# Remove or delete element from list anomaly

Tags: python, list

In Python 2.7, when I have two lists and I remove an element only from the second list why the element is removed from the first list too?

```
x1 = list()
x2 = list()
x1 = ['foo1', 'bar1', 'foo2', 'bar2']
x2 = x1
x2.remove('foo1')
del x2[x2.index('foo2')]
print 'x1:\t', x1
print 'x2:\t', x2
```

The result will be:

```
x1:     ['bar1', 'bar2']
x2:     ['bar1', 'bar2']
```

Does anybody know why?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because of this statement `x2 = x1`. You are just assigning to `x2` the same reference that `x1`. You need to explicitly copy. Something like this:

```
x2 = x1[:]
```

If you find this statement weird, you can use this too:

```
x2 = list(x1)
```

Answer (score 0):

oh, variable assingment and declaration in one step...
So this will work properly:

```
x1 = list()
x1 = ['foo1', 'bar1', 'foo2', 'bar2']
x2 = list(x1)
x2.remove('foo1')
del x2[x2.index('foo2')]
print 'x1:\t', x1
print 'x2:\t', x2
```

The result will be:

```
x1:     ['foo1', 'bar1', 'foo2', 'bar2']
x2:     ['bar1', 'bar2']
```

Nice day!

Comment: You don't need `x1 = list()`. You rebind `x1` in the next line.